# How to initialize BehaviorRelay inside of protocol

Tags: swift, rx-swift

How to initialize `BehaviorRelay` inside of protocol

```swift
protocol ArticlePresentable: Presentable {
  var listener: ArticlePresentableListener? { get set }

  var searchResult: BehaviorRelay<[NewsModel]> =
    BehaviorRelay(value: []) { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't, nor should you try. The best you can do is something like this:

```
protocol ArticlePresentable: Presentable {
    var searchResult: BehaviorRelay<[NewsModel]> { get }
}
```

Note that the property template is only defined as a `{ get }` rather than `{ get set }` because you should never reset a behavior relay.